# Google Chrome MS Windows version 50 : ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, websocket

I have just used a new machine with Google Chrome version 50 under windows (32 & 64 bit sys.) to access a websocket website and I get the following error everytime: ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME

I know the certificate is valid and this error happens solely with this version of Chrome and the Windows platform (tested on linux, mac and with other versions and under Firefox, IE, Safari, etc..).

I am the owner of this website that depends on a working secured socket to service my clients. What should I do to remedy the problem?

Comment: It seems the problem has just magically disappeared overnight? Anyone knows what happen (google fixes it, first time usage bug, is it a temp fix, DNK,...)? It is not the first time, I have seen this issue, as a matter of fact, I experienced it last week on a 64-bit machine and I was able to duplicate the error yesterday on a 32-bit machine. Unfortunately, I don't have the 64-bit machine of hands to see if the issue went away there too. Anyone has experience this problem on others configs?

Comment: I now know what happened. We have issued a certificate with StartCom authority. Per Mozilla security blog (https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/24/distrusting-new-wosign-and-startcom-certificates/), StartCom were backdating certificates and all certificates from them became untrusted on the latest browser versions. In other words, if you have certificates issued by StartCom or by WoSign, you will need to get a refund and find another trusted source for your certificates.